# Retrieving only primary key column numbers from article_tbl and checking against?

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

Would like to figure out how to better retrieve data from database without performance cost.

Plan as follows:

1. `Select id from article table`;
2. store ids in `List<int> arr;`
3. find out last article id. `int x = arr.Count()`
4. `Select * from article_tbl where id = x`; Run query.
5. Post it on you page.

Am I planning right? What is better way of retrieving data from database?

Thanks a lot

Comment: are you just trying to select the latest article and what db are you using ?

Comment: Yes it can be solved like "Select top 1 from article_tbl order by date DESC". Thanks mate. But What is better way of retrieving data from database? I am working with SQLServer Express 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this - you can call it "ad-hoc" or wrap it up in a stored procedure:

```
-- get the "latest" ID from the "Article" latest
-- but you need to define *latest* by WHAT criteria?? A date?? The ID itself??
DECLARE @LastID INT

SELECT TOP 1 @LastID = ID
FROM dbo.Article
ORDER BY ..........  -- order by date? id? what??

-- get the detail data for that ID from the "Article_tbl"
SELECT (list of columns)
FROM dbo.Article_tbl 
WHERE ID = @LastID
```